# Read the packets of bytes on client socket from server socket for connection oriented (TCP) client/server?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

i m creating connection oriented server/client(TCP) socket.i have created whole server socket and i have written packet on server socket successfully and i have created client socket also but i m not be able to read packet so please give me the idea about read the packet(code or example) on client socket and tell clearly that can i read a packet on client socket or not if no then what should use in place of client and server socket

Comment: please add your code.  there is no difference in server or client packet reading. open the socket, get the stream and read from stream or write to it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't generally read a packet at a time - you read from the `InputStream` returned by `Socket.getInputStream()`. You should almost certainly be treating the connection as a stream, rather than even attempting to handle individual packets.

If you still run into problems, it would really help if you could post some code to show how you're connecting the socket etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement such a thing for my networking course in college.

Here's an excerpt from the [book](http://www.aw-bc.com/kurose_ross/)

TCPServer.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer
{
   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
      {
         String clientSentence;
         String capitalizedSentence;
         ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

         while(true)
         {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient =
               new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
         }
      }
}
```

---

TCPClient.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient
{
 public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
 {
  String sentence;
  String modifiedSentence;
  BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
  DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
  BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
  sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
  outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
  modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
  System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
  clientSocket.close();
 }
}
```

Hopefully this will be sufficient to figure out what you did wrong. Good luck!